# C++ Initializer list in the header file of a class

Tags: c++

I have the following class in my `Filer.h` file:

```
#include<string>
#include<boost\filesystem.hpp>
#include<fstream>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

#ifndef FILER_H
#define FILER_H

class Filer()
{
public :
    // I have tried many other syntax, but none of them worked.
    Filer() : fileStr();
    std::fstream& fileStr;
};

#endif
```

Then in my `Filer.cpp`, I have defined it like this:

```
Filer::Filer() : fileStr() 
{

}
```

My problem is that, I want to have an instance of `std::fstream` when the `Filer` class is constructed. I want to have this class assigned to `fileStr` variable. How then should I solve my issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an std::fstream to be contained in this class, simply remove the ampersand from this line:

```
std::fstream& fileStr;
```

to make it:

```
std::fstream fileStr;
```

The fstream will be constructed automatically.

If you want fileStr to refer to a std::fstream defined elsewhere then you need a constructor that takes a reference to that external fstream and uses it to initialize the fileStr reference. That code would look like:

```
Filer(std::fstream & stream) : fileStr(stream) 
{ }
std::fstream& fileStr;
```

If you are defining the constructor in the cpp file you must not specify the bool return value, and you must have the argument so it would look like:

```
Filer::Filer(std::fstream & stream) 
      : fileStr(stream)
{
}
```

Comment: then how should the definition in .cpp file be?

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors, the first is that you should now have the initializer list in the declaration. The other error is that if you want a reference you need to pass a `std::fstream` reference as an argument to the constructor and use that for the initializer.

If the constructor is simple, like the one shown for your class, you can make it an inline function:

```
Filer(std::fstream& str) : fileStr(str)
{}
```